# Is there a way to save two image at once only using one field?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, multer

I want to save two image original one and resized one (for thumbnail)

and I use only one field for image

but I think multer saved original one already on S3 so I couldn't save resized one on S3.

Is there a way to save both image at once only using one field?

```
const single = upload.single('img')

 single(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: errorMessage.UNEXPECTED_FIELD_ERROR + ' (img)'
                })
            }

            let img = req.file //img is already stored on S3 
                            //Now I can't store my thumbnail on S3!

gm(request(img.location))
          .thumbnail('50', '50', '!')
          .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if(err) console.log(err)

            var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/resized.jpg');
            stdout.pipe(writeStream);
          });
          //...
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3-transform#transforming-files-before-upload

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'some-bucket',
    shouldTransform: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, /^image/i.test(file.mimetype))
    },
    transforms: [{
      id: 'original',
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'image-original.jpg')
      },
      transform: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, sharp().jpg())
      }
    }, {
      id: 'thumbnail',
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'image-thumbnail.jpg')
      },
      transform: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, sharp().resize(100, 100).jpg())
      }
    }]
  })
})
```

I used transforms that multer-s3-transform offer, but latest version doen't offer transforms option so I used this code copy and pasted on my multer-s3-transform lib

https://github.com/badunk/multer-s3/pull/56/files